# In jQuery, how can I extract initials from the name field of a form?

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I can think of some real ugly solutions, but I'm hoping some genius out there has an elegant one. I have a form that takes a name as an input and sends that name to a function. Now I need to strip the name down to its initials (e.g. 'John Doe' becomes 'JD') and send that instead.

Any suggestions. (I would say preferably not involving regex, but I've a feeling I'm not going to be lucky on that score.)

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="yourName">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="id.push(yourName)">Tell us your name</button>
</div>
</form>
```

EDIT:
In response to somebody's polite request to provide details of what I've tried:
My thinking is to take a look at the value of the name field on mouseout and extract the initials that way. Unfortunately, although jQuery picks up the mouseout event, it doesn't give any value for the field.

Here's the code in question:

```
$("input[name=yourName]").mouseout(function(){
   console.log($("input[name=yourName]").val());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There's loads of ways to do this but since you would rather avoid using a regular expression you will have to do a *little* bit more work. In this example I simply split the input value into an array of words then take the first letter of each word:

```js
$(function() {
  function getInitials(valStr) {
    var words = valStr.split(" "),
      initials = "";
    words.forEach(function(word) {
      initials += word.charAt(0);
    });
    return initials.toUpperCase();
  }
  $("input[name=yourName]").mouseout(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);
    console.log(getInitials(val));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="yourName" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, Moob.
I can see where I was going wrong now. FWIW, I've come up with another solution. See below.

Comment: Actually, my solution is nearly identical to Moob's, so kudos to him.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is ->

```
<script>
var getInitials = function(name){
    var inits = "";
    var names=name.toUpperCase().split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        inits += names[i].charAt(0)+".";
    }
    return inits;
}
</script>


var initials = "";

 <div class="signup-form">
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" onBlur="initials=getInitials(this.value)" class="form-control" name="yourName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-info" onclick="_id.push(initials)">Sign Up</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```